# How to enable Button after filling all the input field and mobile field with 8digits in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I want to enable my submit button when a user put all the details in the respective field and 8 to 12 digit of mobile number.

Right now my code is accepting only mobile number condition and my button enables when user put 8 digit of mobile number.

But i want him to put all the details and 8 digit of mobile number then only my SUBMIT button should enable

This is my code :

```
<form name="signUpForm" class="list form-margin" ng-submit="submit(data)">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.data.User.name" required>

    <select ng-disabled="show" class="dropdown-full sign-up-select country-dd"
            ng-model="data.data.User.internationalcode">
    <option value="">Country Code</option>
    <option value="+91">(IND)+91</option> 
    </select>

    <input type="text" ng-disabled="show" maxlength="12"
           placeholder="Mobile No" ng-model="data.data.User.mobile"
           ng-keyup="{{data.data.User.mobile.length>=8 ? otpButton=true : otpButton=false}}"
           required>            

    <input type="password" placeholder="Choose a password" 
           class="input-type" ng-model="data.data.User.password" required>

    <div>
       <button id="btn-send-otp" ng-disabled="!otpButton"
               type="submit" ng-click="disableButton($event);sendOTP();">
         Submit
       </button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would use [ng-pattern](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) along with required:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="12"
      placeholder="Mobile No"
      ng-model="data.data.User.mobile"
      ng-pattern="'\\d{8,12}'" required> <!-- Use ng-pattern here -->
```

For your submit button, change the expression for your ng-disabled directive to this:

```
ng-disabled="signUpForm.$invalid"
```

> What is `\\d{8,12}`? It is a simple [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) that says any digits, with a length of 8-12.

More on Angular Forms is [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ng-if or ng-show when the user has filled out all the input fields like:

```
       <button id="btn-send-otp" ng-if="data.data.User.name && data.data.User.internationalcode" ng-disabled="!otpButton" type="submit" ng-click="disableButton($event);sendOTP();">Submit</button>
```

Comment: You are not using AngularJS's built-in form validation. @Brian's answer is much better.